# Assigning a Label to a FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi Im trying to assign  a `label` to a `FlowLayoutPanel` based on the `Value` of a `cell`
My Code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagridview.SelectedRows)
{
    var Id = row.Cells["typeID"].Value.ToString();
    int typeID;

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Id) && int.TryParse(Id, out PlayerID))
    {

        Label label1 = new Label();
        label1.Text = row.Cells["PlayerType"].Value.ToString();

      //Does not matter for type of player
      //flpGoalie.Controls.Add(label1);

      if(label1.Text == "Goalie")
      {
          flpGoalie.Controls.Add(label1);
      }
 }
```

This Line  `flpGoalie.Controls.Add(label1);` , assigns any `label` to that `FlowLayoutPanel`.

What im trying to do is Seperate the `PlayerType` into different `FLP` based on the value of the `cell`.

Comment: Side note: you may add `label1` twice. Is that OK?

Comment: @lan, do you mean i might have added `label1` twice?

Comment: You have two `flpGoalie.Controls.Add(label1);` lines. Is that intended?

Comment: That line was just to show that it can be added to a `FlowLayoutPanel`, no matter what `PlayerType`, when running my code i comment that bit out.

Comment: Ok, now it is clearer. :) one more question: how many FLP do you have? what are their names? or you create FLP dynamically?

Comment: There are 11 FLPs, so flpGoalie, flpLeftBack,flpRightBack.... and so on

Comment: Oh my... and then, is there an *exact pattern* between "PlayerType" and FLP? for instance: if Type = "Goalie", then FLP=flpGoalie, and so on...

Comment: Yes, if Type = Goalie then Label goes into flpGoalie and so on :)

Comment: OK, that's perfect. In that case, you can assign the label to your FLP dynamically using `Controls.Find` :) check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is a pattern between the `FLP` names and the `Text` in the `label1`, you can use `Controls.Find` to find a particular `Control` in your `Form` like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagridview.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>())
{
    var Id = row.Cells["typeID"].Value.ToString();
    int typeID;

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Id) && int.TryParse(Id, out PlayerID))
    {

        Label label1 = new Label();
        label1.Text = row.Cells["PlayerType"].Value.ToString();

      //Does not matter for type of player
      //flpGoalie.Controls.Add(label1);

    Control[] ctrls = Controls.Find("flp" + label1.Text, true);
    if (ctrls != null && ctrls.Length > 0){
        FlowLayoutPanel flp = ctrls[0] as FlowLayoutPanel;
        if(flp != null)
            flp.Controls.Add(label1);
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndroidAL huh? how can that be? If you use all default settings for WinForm it *should* work. :( what does the error say?

Comment: @lan, had label2 instead of label 1 :/, how could i do it for all rows not just `SelectedRows`?

Comment: @AndroidAL all rows instead of just selected rows? You mean the grid rows? and what you do mean by doing for all rows? doing *what*?

Comment: @lan , At the moment  you have to select a row first how can i do it for all rows in the dgv instead of just selecting one row in dgv?

Comment: can it just give me all without selecting?

Comment: @AndroidAL yes, you can. That will be `List<DataRow> rows = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();`

Comment: Where would i put that? could you modify your answer?

Comment: @lan, thanks, but getting `Cannot convert type 'System.Data.DataRow' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow' 
`

Comment: @AndroidAL sorry, my bad. It should be `Cast<DataGridViewRow>` ;s will update my answer